Why $(g\circ f)(\omega)$ must be compact if $g$ is continuous....
Let $\omega =\cup_{i=1}^5(i,i+1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable such that $f'(x)=0\forall x\in \omega$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be any function, then which of the following is true?

If g is continuous then $(g\circ f)\omega$ is compact set in $\mathbb{R}$

If g is differentiable and $g'(x)>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $(g\circ f)\omega$ have precisely 5 elements.

If g is continuous and surjective then $(g\circ f)(\omega)\cap \mathbb{Q}=\phi$

If g is differentiable then $\{{e^x:x\in (g\circ f)(\omega) \}}$ does not contain any nonempty open interval.


What I Understood. $\omega=(1,2)\cup (2,3)\cup (3,4)\cup(4,5)\cup (5,6)$ and it is given $f'(x)=0 \forall x \in \omega$ implies $f(x)$ is a constant function for all $x\in \omega$ say $f(x)=k$ that is $f(\omega)=k$
Here I am doubtful about option 1 . I know option 2 cannot be true as $(g\circ f)(\omega)$ must be singleton.
For option 1, if g is continuous then $g\circ f$ is also continuous since $f$ is continuous.But I cannot conclude anything about $(g\circ f)(\omega)$. If $\omega$ was compact set then we can say continuous image of compact set is compact so $(g\circ f)(\omega)$ is also compact. But $\omega $ is clearly not closed.
for option 3. Since $f(x)=k, \forall x\in \omega$ implies $(g\circ f)(\omega)=g(f(\omega))=g(k)$ now it depends on value of $g(k)$.If $g(k)\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $(g\circ f)\omega \in \mathbb{Q}$ and hence $(g\circ f)\omega \cap \mathbb{Q}\neq \phi$ otherwise empty. So cannot conclude option 3 also.
Option 4. This must be true. Since $(g\circ f)(\omega)$ is singleton set so cannot contain any open set.
But it is given option 1 and 4 are correct.
Am I correct...
Thanks in advance!!

Notice that $f: \omega \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiably and not $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiably, thus we can have $f(x) = k_1 $ for $x \in (1,2)$, $f(x) = k_2$ for $x \in (2,3)$, and so on.

But can you help me with option one why it should  be correct?

Well the range of $f$ is a finite set, and thus the range of $g \circ f$ is also a finite set. Finite sets are compact.
